# Spring Boot - Declaring beans from a third party security chain

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm working on a common utilities package to be shared between Spring Boot projects. The common package contains several annotated beans which are imported and declared in a `@Configuration` class inside the importing application, like this user filter:

```
// common package
package com.org.common_package.filters;
...
@Component
@Order(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE - 1)
public class UserFilter implements Filter {
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;
...
```

```
// application imports common_package
package com.org.application.config;

import com.org.common_package.filters.UserFilter;

@Configuration
public class CommonConfig {
    @Bean
    public UserFilter userFilter() {
        return new UserFilter();
    }
...
```

The one that's causing me trouble is this `@EnableWebSecurity` class, which declares its own `@Bean`s for SecurityFilterChain and JwtDecoder:

```
package com.org.common_package.security;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.NimbusJwtDecoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class CommonSecurity {

    @Value("${jwk.url}")
    private String jwkUrl;

    private final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CommonSecurity.class);

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        logger.debug("In HTTP Security Filter Chain");
        http.authorizeRequests((authorizeRequests) -> authorizeRequests
                .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .oauth2ResourceServer((oauth2ResourceServer) -> oauth2ResourceServer
                        .jwt((jwt) -> jwt
                                .decoder(jwtDecoder())));
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
        logger.debug("In jwt Decoder");
        NimbusJwtDecoder jwtDecoder_ = NimbusJwtDecoder.withJwkSetUri(jwkUrl).build();
        jwtDecoder_.setClaimSetConverter(new UsernameSubClaimAdapter());
        return jwtDecoder_;
    }
}
```

I'm not sure how to declare these beans in CommonConfig in the importing application, since their constructors require other objects. Any HTTP request I send after booting the app returns 401 unauthorized, and the debug logs don't show either log line inside CommonSecurity, while showing messages for missing beans like this:

```
SpringBootWebSecurityConfiguration.WebSecurityEnablerConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity' (OnClassCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (names: springSecurityFilterChain; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)
```

Pulling the CommonSecurity class out of the common package and putting it into the importing application as is causes it to work fine. How can I declare the missing beans for this imported package?

Comment: i would recommend looking into creating a custom starter, than a library that will randomly load in beans.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `@ComponentScan("com.org.*")` annotation on the main class successfully made all beans in the common package available to the application.